# How to draw a polygon with Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to draw a simple polygon shape using Phaser 3 framework. The problem is: the polygon doesnt show up.

```
var config = {
        type:Phaser.AUTO,
        width:800,
        height:600,
        scene: {
            preload: preload,
            create: create,
        }
    };

    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

    var poly;
    var graphics;

    function preload() {}

    function create() {

        poly = new Phaser.Geom.Polygon();
        poly.setTo([ new Phaser.Geom.Point(200, 100), new Phaser.Geom.Point(350, 100), new Phaser.Geom.Point(375, 200), new Phaser.Geom.Point(150, 200) ]);


        graphics = this.add.graphics(0, 0);
        graphics.fillPoints(poly.points, true);
    }
```

The error i got is: "Phaser.Polygon is not a constructor",
but i saw that code on a tutorial about Phaser.

EDIT: I changed the code as suggested by PhotonStorm, now i dont get errors but the polygon still doesnt appear.

EDIT2: solved by calling lineStyle and fillStyle on graphics object.

```
graphics = this.add.graphics(0, 0);

graphics.lineStyle(5, 0xFF00FF, 1.0);
graphics.fillStyle(0xFFFFFF, 1.0);
graphics.fillPoints(poly.points, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `Phaser.Geom.Polygon`.

[Here is the docs page for it](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Geom.Polygon.html).

A basic example:

```
    var polygon = new Phaser.Geom.Polygon([
        400, 100,
        200, 278,
        340, 430,
        650, 80
    ]);
```

Comment: How do I change the points position in game?